# openmp computation time is not improved proportionally to thread number

Tags: performance, time, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I have a fortran program using openmp which is simplified as below:

```
program test
      use omp_lib
      use function_module
      use data_module
      implicit none
      real*8 :: theta,f
      
      call readdata()
      call func_subroutine(theta,f)
end program

subroutine func_subroutine(theta,f)
       use omp_lib
       use data_module
       implicit none
       integer :: i
       real*8 :: theta,f
       real*8 :: t1,t2,t_vec(20),tsum

       !$omp parallel do shared(data_variables,t_vec) private(i,t1,t2)
       do i=1,20
            ! read individual data
          
            ! count time
            t1=omp_get_wtime()
            call func(theta,f_ind)
            t2=omp_get_wtime()
            t_vec(i)=t2-t1
       end do
       !$end omp parallel do

       tsum=sum(t_vec)
end subroutine
```

In short, I calculate the function value for individual 1  (f_ind) for 20 times. And tsum only counts the time of calculating f_ind.
With 5 threads, tsum=7.2s, and the program takes 33s (without considering the time spent on the subroutine readdata()).
However, with 10 threads, tsum=9.5s, and the program takes 20s.
And with 20 threads, tsum=12s, and the program takes 12s.

The computation time is not improved proportionally to thread number I am using. I am very confused. Is there something wrong?

Comment: You should use `omp_get_wtime()` before and after the parallel block, not inside.

Comment: Who knows, we have no idea what the function does.

Comment: You also have "read individual data" in the parallel region. Unless you have some kind of parallel system that won't speed up and could easily dominate the function (whatever it is doing). We really need more details.

Comment: `f_ind` and `data_variables` are undeclared. And without knowing what `func()` does it's impossible to comment. A general comment is that not all codes scale well on a large number threads. 12" on 20 threads is not too bad compared to 33" on 5 threads

Comment: @Laci If I count time outside the block, it takes 33s with 5 threads, 20s with 10 threads, and 12s with 20 threads.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава the function is a likelihood function to calculate the probability of X with bounds. Will that affect the parallel time?

Comment: ~3 times quicker when going from 5 to 20 threads is, in general, very good scaling and generally I would be very happy with it. Is there a reason you expect it to be better?

Comment: @IanBush Yes. I expect the speed improve 8 times from using 5 threads to 40 threads with more data. However, it only improved 4 times. I found this slowing down becoming worse with larger dataset.

Comment: These values of speed up are typical for a threaded program. Many factors can affect the speed up, not least the available memory bandwidth across a large shared memory region. Without detailed profiling and a complete example of what you are doing we can say no more. Summary: This is typical, you *never* get perfect speed up.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law ?